# Custom SharePoint 2010 Timer job not running

Tags: development, timer-jobs

I have created a custom timer service to create a list. It's scheduled in minute using `FeatureActivated` event. I was able to globally deploy the solution. But the my timer job is not running. It's showing last run time N/A. Is there any solution?

My Execute method

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId) { ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://mymachine:0909"); Web site = clientContext.Web;

    ListCreationInformation listCreationInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
    listCreationInfo.Title = "Test Mailer List";
    listCreationInfo.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.GenericList;
    List list = site.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);

    Field field1 = list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(
              @"<Field Type='Choice'
              DisplayName='Category'
              Format='Dropdown'>
         <Default>Specification</Default>
         <CHOICES>
           <CHOICE>Specification</CHOICE>
           <CHOICE>Development</CHOICE>
           <CHOICE>Test</CHOICE>
           <CHOICE>Documentation</CHOICE>
         </CHOICES>
       </Field>", true, AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
    Field field2 = list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(
        @"<Field Type='Number'
              DisplayName='Estimate'/>", true, AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

And Event receiver class

public class Feature1EventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver {

```
public const string jobName = "BdayTimer";
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPWebApplication webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
    DeleteJob(webApp.JobDefinitions);
    TimerJobTest myJob = new TimerJobTest(webApp);

    SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
    schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
    schedule.EndSecond = 59;
    schedule.Interval = 1;

    myJob.Schedule = schedule;
    myJob.Update();

}


// Uncomment the method below to handle the event raised before a feature is deactivated.

public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPWebApplication webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
    DeleteJob(webApp.JobDefinitions);
}

public void DeleteJob(SPJobDefinitionCollection job1)
{
    foreach (SPJobDefinition job in job1)
    {
        if (job.Name.Equals(jobName))
            job.Delete();
    }
```

Comment: Check out the ULS logs?

Comment: Have you restarted the Timer Service (SPTimerV4) since deploying your WSP?

Comment: and are you sure properties.Feature.Parent is an SPWebApplication (rather than an SPSite?)

Comment: I have checked the ULS logs , also tried restarting its not executing. But its working fine in another server.

Comment: Could it be the wrong system time on your server that does not work properly with your timer job?

Answer (score 1):

go through below link, its working perfectly...

http://www.thesharepointblog.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=815f255a-d0ef-4258-be2a-28487dc9975c&ID=57

Comment: My code is working fine on another server. I cant figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following steps if you are doing it on dev VM:

After deployment of the WSP and activating the feature, restrat timer service.
In Visual studio attach OWSTimer process and attach breakpoint at Execute method.
Then go to the Timer Job definition and select the timer job and click Run Now.

Comment: I have done that too. Still no hope. Buts  its working fine in another server.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Difference is that on production server farm has 3 web applications, on dev one there is only 1